# Integration by parts but not in terms of dx

Tags: integration

I have a question regarding the following integration. How do we integral

$\int_0^\infty x d(e^{-sx})$.

The answer is

$xe^{-sx}|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}dx$.

I am not sure how to solve this. I can only solve integrals in terms of $dx$ so this one really confuses me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is $s$ a real constant?

Comment: First of all its useful to understand what the notation means: $df(x)$  is just a shorthand notation for $f'(x) dx$ so the integral here is  just $\int -sxe^{-sx}dx$. The reason this notation is used and why its useful is described below (it allows you to perform integration by parts).

Comment: @Winther: It's not true that $\mathrm d f(x)$ is a short for $f'(x)\mathrm d x$ (even when $f$ is derivable a.e.). Take the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $F:[0,1]\to [0,1]$. Then $F'(x)dx=0$ a.e. but $\int_0^1 dF(x)=1$. You need more assumption to have $\,\mathrm d f(x)=f'(x)\,\mathrm d x$ (as $\mathcal C^1$ or absolutely continuity).

Comment: @Surb Very interesting your comment.

Comment: @Surb I disagree. Pedagogically, it *is* true at the level this question is asked at. One needs to level up 3 more levels or so before that gets relevant.

Comment: @Winther: There is no pedagogically truth when something is wrong ! It's just not true that $\mathrm d f(x)=f'(x)\,\mathrm d x$ in general (even when $f$ is derivable a.e. which is already a rather strong assumption). Here it indeed works because $x\mapsto e^{-sx}$ is $\mathcal C^1$. But this condition is crucial, and is not a small detail that you can avoid as you seem to pretend.

Comment: @Surb My comment was to OP and the very basic level this question is given at. I don't think its very useful to list all the caveats when teaching basic things and that's why you don't learn everything in the first course you take. Its of course perfectly fine to point this out, but in my experience adding tons of high level details just serves to confuse rather than enlighten and that was my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration by parts formula is
$$\int u\,\mathrm{d}v=uv-\int v\,\mathrm{d}u$$
which you can use in this case with $u=x$ and $v=e^{-sx}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $s>0$. Since $x\mapsto e^{-sx}$ is $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$,

$$\int_0^\infty x\,\mathrm d (e^{-sx})=\int_0^\infty x\cdot \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}(e^{-sx})\,\mathrm d x$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now

Answer (score 1):

The by-parts rule is precisely

$$\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du$$

and is immediately applicable here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it.

Comment: All the question are correct and for me are +1.